# Angular: Pass form control value on blur in dynamic forms

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I want to call a service on blur of a textbox in a dynamic form. Below is my code.

```
<div formArrayName="rows">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let row of manualDetailsForm.get('rows').controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
  <div class="col-xs-1 text-right">
    <span (click)="addDetailManual()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
    <span (click)="removeDetailManual(i)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" *ngIf="i != 0"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    **pass accountName to function on blur**
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="accountName" (blur)="getAccountAssociatedDetails(accountName)"> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="huid">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="huidName">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="huidCountry">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to pass accountName on blur to a function. But I'm getting undefined there. Below is the formGroup in the code.

```
this.manualDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            rows: this.formBuilder.array([this.formBuilder.group({
                accountName: [],
                huid: [],
                huidName: [],
                huidCountry: []
            })])
        })
```

Comment: How does your formGroup look like?

Comment: If you want to get FormControl then you can try `getAccountAssociatedDetails(manualDetailsForm.get(['rows', i, 'accountName']))`

Comment: `manualTPIForm.get(['rows', i, 'accountName'])` should return your control

Comment: Ya... That works... Just wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this.